# AWS Environment variable provider not accepting credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I'm connecting dynamoDb locally using the below code

```
$dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(dirname(__DIR__, 2));
    $dotenv->load();
    $this->key = getenv('aws_access_key_id');
    $this->secret = getenv('aws_secret_access_key');
    $this->dynamodb = new DynamoDbClient([
        'profile' => 'default',
        'region' => 'us-east-1',
        'version' => 'latest',
        'credentials' => [
            'key' => $this->key,
            'secret' => $this->secret,
        ]
    ]);
```

My `.env` file

```
aws_access_key_id = ....
aws_secret_access_key = ....
```

I'm getting this error

```
Type: Aws\Exception\CredentialsException
Message: Cannot read credentials from /Users/user/.aws/credentials
File: /path/to/project/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Credentials/CredentialProvider.php
Line: 394
```

Tried the basic hard-coding of `access key` & `secret key` as well but it doesn't seem to be working rather every time it's fetching from the default path `~/.aws/credentials`

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to print the environment variable to make sure your application is getting those environment variables.

It is not finding it from those variables. You need to export them before you run this script.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT1:**

```
use Aws\Common\Credentials\Credentials;

$credentials = new Credentials('YOUR_ACCESS_KEY', 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY');
```

//assign these credentials to Dynamodbclient

**EDIT2:**  AWS SDK 3.x follows different way to initialize.

```
$sdk = new Aws\Sdk([
    'credentials' => $credentials,
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'DynamoDb' => [
        'region' => 'us-west-2',
    ],
]);

$dynamodb = $sdk->createDynamoDb();  // This is dynamodb client
```

Comment: FYI printing the `env` variables does work i.e. prints the given values

Comment: Updated answer, please try and update if that works.

Comment: It still gives the same error `$credentials = new Credentials('...', '...');
        $this->dynamodb = new DynamoDbClient([
            'profile' => 'default',
            'region' => 'us-east-1',
            'version' => 'latest',
            'credentials' => $credentials
        ]);`

Comment: which version of sdk do you use?

Comment: I'm using `3.36``"aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.36"`

Comment: sdk 3 follows different syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Try without specifying:

```
'profile' => 'default'
```

You want to use the default profile that is specified in the credentials file. It is possible the SDK looks at this line and try to open the credentials file and look for `default` profile. I don't have PHP SDK installed to verify this..

Comment: Yes, if you specify both the 'profile' and 'credentials' seems like 'profile' takes precedence.